# Adding text to a notification icon

Tags: android, icons, statusbar, android-notifications, android-icons

I want to make a notification icon with text over it, to show for example the percent battery remaining. Is there a way to do that that doesn't involve 100+ separate icons?

I've looked all over but couldn't find a way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100+ separate icons unfortunately. Because of security reasons android only accepts resource IDs that also must not be custom resource type.

Would be happy to know if I'm wrong though.

Comment: Ok then, next question: Is there any way of quickly generating 100 similar icons?

Comment: That's where you can use android canvases and save bitmaps to file. In a separate application of course.

Comment: No news for this for the modern age (2022)?